# Stored procedure clarification - replicate ,charIndex and convert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following line of code in a stored procedure that I am having an difficult time understanding:

```
REPLICATE(''*'', charindex(convert(varchar(1), o.RestrictedB), ''1'')) + op.Prefix
WHERE o.RestrictedB = 1 || 0
AND op.Prefix = 'Test'
```

I get the replicate, I assume it will prepend `op.Prefix` with `x` amount of `***` but I'm a little confused as to what is happening with the `convert` and `charindex`.

Comment: Convert is simply converting the type (probably bit) to varchar.  Charindex is searching for a 1, if it finds it it returns its position/index.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a very arduous say of saying:

```
(case when o.Restricted = 1 then '*' else '' end) + op.Prefix
```

The idea appears to be to check the value '0' or '1' by looking for its position in the string '1'.  This will return either 0 or 1, which is the replication factor for `replicate()`.

If I had to guess, this code was copied from somewhere that had a longer string than "1" for the `charindex()`.  The simplification to a single character is confusing (it would be confusing enough with a longer search string for `charindex()` but it would make more sense).

Comment: No kidding... They really over complicated this one.